Enhancing Script for Better Visual Presentation
Is anyone here who can help improve my script? I want the results to be more visually presentable. Is is possible to include in HTML code?
function showAEdata() {
var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
var input = ui.prompt("Please enter your First Name and Last Name.", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);

if (input.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Monitoring (Database)");
var data = ws.getRange("A2:X" + ws.getLastRow()).getValues();
var userSelectedRep = input.getResponseText().toLowerCase();

    var newData = data.filter(function (r) {
      return r[6].toLowerCase() == userSelectedRep;
    });
    
    var yearInput = ui.prompt("Please enter the year (e.g., 2024):", ui.ButtonSet.OK_CANCEL);
    
    if (yearInput.getSelectedButton() == ui.Button.OK) {
      var selectedYear = yearInput.getResponseText();
      var filteredYearData = newData.filter(function (r) {
        var date = new Date(r[5]);
        return date.getFullYear() == selectedYear;
      });
    
      var selectedColumns = filteredYearData.map(function (r) {
        return [r[1], r[2], r[4], r[5], r[9], r[10], r[11], r[17]];
      });
    
      if (filteredYearData.length > 0) {
        var newWs = ss.insertSheet(userSelectedRep);
        var headers = ["INSTITUTION", "MONTH", "JO NUMBER", "DATE RELEASED", "TYPE OF USER", "PLATFORM", "TYPE OF ACCESS", "NUMBER OF ACCESS CODE"];
    
        newWs.getRange(4, 3, selectedColumns.length, selectedColumns[0].length).setValues(selectedColumns);
        newWs.getRange(3, 3, 1, headers.length).setValues([headeenter code herers]);
    
      } else {
        ui.alert("No matching data found for the entered year.");
      }
    } else {
      ui.alert("Year input canceled.");
    }

} else {
ui.alert("Operation Canceled.");
}
}

This the current result of my Script I want to enhance it by using HTML etc.


This is the code that I used for the charts.
if (filteredYearData.length > 0) {
        var newWs = ss.insertSheet(userSelectedRep);
        var range = newWs.getRange("A2:H" + ws.getLastRow());
        var chart = newWs.newChart()
            .setChartType(Charts.ChartType.BAR) // Set the chart type
            .addRange(range) // Add the data range
            .setOption('title', 'INSTITUTION DATA')
            .setOption('vAxis.title', 'INSTITUTION')
            .setOption('hAxis.title', 'NUMBER OF CODES')
            .setPosition(1, 10, 0, 0) // Position of the chart (row, column, offsetX, offsetY)
            .build();

        newWs.insertChart(chart);
  
 
        var headers = ["INSTITUTION", "MONTH", "JO NUMBER", "DATE RELEASED", "TYPE OF USER", "PLATFORM", "TYPE OF ACCESS", "NUMBER OF ACCESS CODE"];


What does "enhance it by using HTML etc." mean? What exactly do you wish to accomplish? Please clarify your question to ask about a specific problem.

For example, the header is in bold. On the other side, there are graphs that display the percentages, and it would be great to have a background as well. is it possible?

Would you be able to provide your sample sheet, with your initial output, and also your expected output so that we can further help you. You may use this anonymous sheet maker to create your reproducible example without your email being exposed.

@Patsytalk
I'm not sure if I followed the instructions correctly. Please find the link to my sample output below. (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1TINWVDazpwXjCvzK9zW9YovI73ZEyNMwnFhlt4UU_bY/edit?gid=2100307022#gid=2100307022)

Have you used your browser devtools inspect facility to see what HTML is produced? From that you can work out how to select various elements so CSS can be applied. Without an example of the HTML or a definition of what you want it to look like we can't really help. When you have added both those to your question (not on an external site) maybe tagging your question with CSS will get you the help you need.

It appears that you have considerable scripting skill. I suggest that you lookup the "Range" methods for setBackground and setFontWeight.

there are graphs that display the percentages, and it would be great to have a background as well Please include an example of the expected outcome.

Regarding graphs/charts, I suggest that you research the visualisation methods; these include setting a background and font colour,

This is my first time using a script, and I’ve already attempted it, but I'm not sure how to begin.

This is my first time using a script Really?? The script included in the question demonstrates competency with scripting. So you didn't write this script? You should have made this clear at the outset. and I’ve already attempted it Would you please edit the question to include the your attempt at a script and describe the problem you are having with it.

You want to format the output of the header based on an existing script. Specifically:

Background color setBackground
Font weight setFontWeight
Font size setFontSize
Wrap cells setWrap
Vertical alignment setVerticalAlignment
Horizontal alignment setHorizontalAlignment
Set row height setRowHeight
Set column widths setColumnWidth


INSERT NEW ROWS
Existing code
    newWs.getRange(3, 3, 1, headers.length).setValues([headers]);

  } else {

New code
 newWs.getRange(3, 3, 1, headers.length).setValues([headers])
  // format the header range
  newWs.getRange(3, 3, 1, headers.length)
    .setBackground("#a4c2f4")
    .setFontWeight("bold")
    .setFontSize(12)
    .setWrap(true)
    .setVerticalAlignment("middle")
    .setHorizontalAlignment("center")
  // set the row height
  newWs.setRowHeight(3, 57);
  // set the column widths
  var colWidths = [247,100,206,106,110,114,115,130]
  // loop through the columns and set width from array
  // Column 3 to Column 10
  for (var c=3;c<11;c++){
    newWs.setColumnWidth(c, colWidths[+c-3]);
  }
} else {


BEFORE

AFTER

